# Download using jsPDF on a mobile devices

Tags: pdf, mobile, download, tablet, jspdf

I have a page that includes a download button using jsPDF. On desktop machines it downloads the page as it should. However, `pdf.save()` does not work on my tablet or phone.

I tried to add a special case for mobile devices to open the PDF in a new window, since mobile devices don't download things the same as desktops, with the idea being that once the PDF is open in a new window the user can choose to save it manually.

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

html2canvas($("#pdf-area"), {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        $("#pdf-canvas").append(canvas);
        $("#pdf-canvas canvas").css("padding", "20px");
    }
});

var options = {
    pagesplit: true
};

function download(doctitle) {
    pdf.addHTML($("#pdf-area")[0], options, function () {
        if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');           
        } else {
            pdf.save(doctitle);
        }        
    });
}
```

But the download function still does nothing on my tablet/phone. I tested it with this to make sure the pdf.output() function was working:

```
    pdf.addHTML($("#pdf-area")[0], options, function () {
        pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');                
    });
```

and it does still work on desktop, but does nothing on mobile.

Comment: Is there an error? Mobile is known to have some quirks.

Answer (score 5):

**jsPDF** won't download files on mobile apps by this **pdf.save()**. I have tried and searched for this issue but could not find a complete solution in one place. I am using the **file and file-opener plugin**. I have developed the solution in **Ionic React**. Install below modules.

```
npm i jspdf
npm install cordova-plugin-file
npm install @ionic-native/file
npm install cordova-plugin-file-opener2
npm install @ionic-native/file-opener
ionic cap sync
```

2. Go to your file and add these import statements.

```js
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
import 'jspdf-autotable';
import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener;
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { isPlatform } from "@ionic/react";
```

3. Check the **pdfDownload** function

```js
const pdfDownload = async () => {
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text("Example jsPDF", 35, 25)
let pdfOutput = doc.output();
    if (isPlatform("android")) {
      // for Android device
      const directory = File.externalRootDirectory + 'Download/';
      const fileName = `invoice-${new Date().getTime()}.pdf`
      File.writeFile(directory, fileName, pdfOutput, true).then(succ => {
        FileOpener.showOpenWithDialog(directory + fileName, 'application/pdf')
          .then(() => console.log('File opened'))
          .catch(error => console.log('Error opening file', error));
      },
        err => {
          console.log(" writing File error : ", err)
        })
    } else if (isPlatform("ios")) {
      // for iOS device
      console.log('ios device')
      const directory = File.tempDirectory;
      const fileName = `invoice-${new Date().getTime()}.pdf`
      File.writeFile(directory, fileName, pdfOutput, true).then(success => {
        FileOpener.showOpenWithDialog(directory + fileName, 'application/pdf')
          .then(() => console.log('File opened'))
          .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
      },
        err => {
          console.log(" writing File error : ", err)
        })
    } else {
      // for desktop
      doc.save("invoice.pdf");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue.

jsPDF won't download file on phones/ tablets / ipads using "**pdf.save()**".

Do it through File plugin if you are using cordova/phonegap, this will save pdf file in downloads folder (Android) - for the ios you can access pdf file through a path (which is saved somewhere in temp directory) and can send or share.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution of download on mobile with jspdf

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
{
     var blob = pdf.output();
     window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
}
else
{
     pdf.save('filename.pdf');
}
```

Comment: Gives error: `[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed."`

Comment: Received `Uncaught TypeError: Blob constructor: Argument 1 can't be converted to a sequence.` Solved it with this: `window.open(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob])))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example if you're using the Cordova platform for your development:

https://github.com/saharcasm/Cordova-jsPDF-Email

The workaround of the pdf not being downloaded in the devices is to use cordova-plugin-file.

Use the output method on the doc that will give you the raw pdf which needs to be written & saved in a file.

For example,

```
var doc = new JsPDF(); 
//... some work with the object
var pdfOutput = doc.output("blob"); //returns the raw object of the pdf file
```

The pdfOutput is then written on an actual file by using the file plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way which works on both Desktop and Mobile is to use:

`window.open(doc.output("bloburl"), "_blank");`

Comment: it doesnt work :(