# Give jspdf() blob a filename

Tags: mobile, blob, jspdf

I am using jspdf() on mobile devices which doesn't work in the same way as on desktops for saving the resulting pdf.  I found this workaround on here using a blob - [Download using jsPDF on a mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885825/download-using-jspdf-on-a-mobile-devices/32581750#32581750) which does create a pdf that opens on a mobile device.  My only issue is the file is then called blob - which is not very professional in my view - and if the file is then opened in say ibooks it shows as unknown as there are no file details.

This is the code I am using

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
{
   var blob = pdf.output();
   window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
}
else
{
   pdf.save('results.pdf');
}
```

Is there a way to name the blob?

Comment: What's unprofessional about "blob"?  It stands for "Binary Large OBject".

Comment: To a programmer maybe, but to the man on the street it has other meanings - http://www.dictionary.com/browse/blob - so I'd like to call my file results.pdf

Comment: I tried to use the various options in the var declaration, such aspdf.output('D','charts') but that stops it working at all

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file and then give a name to file:

```js
pdfAttachment : Files; //declare the file
newName = 'new_file_name'      
this.pdfAttachment = new File([doc.output('blob')], newName, {
      type: doc.output('blob').type,
      lastModified: doc.output('blob').lastModified,
    });
```