# How to Generate and Share PDF on Android/IOS Device using jsPDF for PDF and SharePicker for Sharing in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, pdf-generation, ionic4, share

**home.html**

```
<ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button (click)="sharePicker()">
      <ion-icon name="Share-alt" color="light"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab>
```

**home.ts**

```
async sharePicker() {
var doc = new jsPDF();
var col = ["Id", "Brand name"];
var rows = [];
this.brand.forEach(element => {
  var temp = [
    element.id,
    element.name,
  ];
  console.log("temp", temp)
  rows.push(temp);

});
doc.autoTable(col, rows);
doc.save("BrandList.pdf");

this.platform.ready()
  .then(() => {
    this.socialSharing.share(null, null, doc.save("BrandList.pdf"), null)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('Shared via SharePicker');
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Was not shared via SharePicker');
      });
   });
  }
```

Items List get Directly to the `Database` and Added to the `col` Parameter,

I want when i click `FAB` Button, then `PDF` Generate Automatically, and open the share Option and Send `PDF` on Social Media, like, whatsapp, fb, etc

this code generate `PDF` in Browser but not on Device.

Answer (score 0):

jsPDF won't download file on phones/ tablets / ipads using "pdf.save()".

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31912801/7907226)

The options to send directly via social share is use email with file Param
or you can also upload via Firebase and share only the url

Example using Firebase:

```
uploadPDF(selected) {  
    return firebase.storage().ref(this.pathFinal).child('/path/').putString(selected, 'data_url')
  }
```

Then:

```
upload(){        
    let loading = this.uiUtils.showLoading("uploading...")
    loading.present()

    this.storage.uploadPDF('pathtopdf')

      .then(snapshot => {

        snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
          loading.dismiss()
            console.log('Share this url: ' + url)
            this.uiUtils.showAlertSuccess('Success')
          })

        }).catch(err => {
          loading.dismiss()
          this.idUrl = ""
          this.uiUtils.showAlert("Atenção", err).present()

        })
      })
      .catch( error => {
        loading.dismiss()
        this.uiUtils.showAlert("Atenção", error).present()

      }).catch(errorSend => {
        loading.dismiss()
        this.uiUtils.showAlert("Atenção", errorSend).present()
      })      
  }
```

Comment: so which plugging i use for downloading PDF on Phones?